# $.getJSON() returned error when i wanted to recieve json array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I want to get Json array which is echoed in php file. Problem is that when i execute $.getJSON in client i get error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character, return window.JSON.parse( data + "" );
```

Code:
php:

```
echo json_encode($responseVar);
```

Json array is visible in the source: {"resp":0}

js:

```
$.getJSON('../views/application.php', function(data) {
    alert('alert1');
    if(data) {
        document.write(data.resp);
        alert('alert2');
    }
    else {
        alert('error');
    }
})
.fail(function(j,t,e) {
    console.error(e);
 });
```

I don't get any alert, i just get the described error.

Comment: The obviuos next step is to post the JSON instead of the code. Search Google for online json validator

Comment: Just an idea: Do you set the Content-type to application/json?

Comment: I set it but it still doesn't work

Comment: I would have thought it was probably an error parsing the JSON that has been returned as mentioned above. Check that your JSON is valid.

Comment: Json: {"resp":0}, and it's valid.

Comment: There might be some weird hidden characters that is breaking the response. Set the bugger to break on all errors and inspect the variable data. Also do not use document.write to debug, use the console!

Comment: Is anything else being `echo`ed along with `json_encode($responseVar)`? jQuery will try to parse the entire response, so any other output is likely to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put it in a function:

```
function getJsonArray()
    {
    var URL="/URL";
    $.ajax(
        {
        type        : "GET",
        url         : processURL,
        cache       : false,
        dataType    : "json",
        success     : function (Put the array name here) 
            {Do Something with the array    }};
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple reasons:

- the BOM encoding: Switch off BOM (encoding UTF-8 without BOM) in text editor. BOM is a system (not visible) symbols in the begining of UTF8 file.
- jQuery 1.4 onwards the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner. Any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. Set the header correctly:

  > header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
  >
  > header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
  >
  > header('Content-type: application/json');
- wrong status code from the server.